# running SSIS from another computer

Tags: ssis

I have server AAA with a SQL Server database instance and a few SSIS packages in the file system. All SSIS packages have input parameters. I launch them them manually using SQL Server Management Studio - Integration Services. I have a server BBB only with SQL Server Management Studio. Server BBB can access the database on server AAA. From server BBB I can see the SSIS packages from server AAA, but when I try to run one of them I get the error message:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must
>   install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher

Do I really need a SQL Server Standard Edition on server BBB?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do here. Do you just want to initiate the execution of the packages from machine BBB? Or do you want the packages to run against machine BBB as opposed to AAA? Have you tried installing SQL Server Data Tools on BBB?

Comment: I want to initiate the execution from machine BBB. My understanding is that  SQL Server Data Tools helps to run SSIS packages within Visual Studio.

Comment: Data Tools is a component of Visual Studio where SSIS, SSAS and SSRS packages can be developed.

Comment: You mentioned SSIS packages in the file system and you also mentioned running them from SSMS. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: I do not have Visual Studio on these machines. I have only SSMS.

Comment: Problem solved after I installed Integration Services on server BBB